# What is wrong with this MODAL ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I work so hard to follow the steps of [this](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/modal-login-jquery/index.html) MODAL login, but for some reason I'm getting nowhere! Very frustrating.

So [this](http://examscan.us/shulemberger/#loginmodal) is the webpage that I'm working on. Everything is followed and it's suppose to work.

I will briefly point out the code snippets:

Right on top of the page there's the css styling:

```css
<style type="text/css">


/** modal window styles **/
#lean_overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
}
 
#loginmodal {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #f3f6fa;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
 
#loginform { /* no default styles */ }
 
#loginform label { display: block; font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: bold; color: #7c8291; margin-bottom: 3px; }
 
.txtfield { 
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #7988a3;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#edf3f9), to(#fff));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #edf3f9, #fff);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #edf3f9, #fff);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #edf3f9, #fff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #edf3f9, #fff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #edf3f9, #fff);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #abbce8 #c3cae0 #b9c8ef;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
}
 
.txtfield:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: #525864;
  border-color: #84c0ee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 7px #96c7ec;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 7px #96c7ec;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 7px #96c7ec;
}


</style>
```

I also added to the header section the 2 .js file links that are associated:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://examscan.us/shulemberger/wp-includes/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
src="http://examscan.us/shulemberger/wp-includes/js/jquery.leanModal.min.js">
</script>
```

Then, right on top of the webpage I have the link to the MODAL:

```html
<li><a  href="#loginmodal" class="flatbtn" id="modaltrigger">Sign in</a></li>
    <li><a class="flatbtn" id="modaltrigger" href="#loginmodal">Sign up</a></li>
```

And finally, on the bottom of the page I have the modal code:

```html
<div id="loginmodal" style="display:none;">
    <h1>User Login</h1>
    <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="index.html">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="txtfield" tabindex="1">
      
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="txtfield" tabindex="2">
      
      <div class="center"><input type="submit" name="loginbtn" id="loginbtn" class="flatbtn-blu hidemodal" value="Log In" tabindex="3"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/ -> How To Use -> Step 3: call the function on your modal trigger, as follows. Be sure to set the href attribute of your trigger anchor to match the id of your target element.

```
$("#trigger_id").leanModal();
```

...or, if you want more than one modal window on the same page, simply add the 'rel' attribute to your triggers, and call the function by attribute, like so:

```
$("a[rel*=leanModal]").leanModal();
```

I don't see this instruction in the provided code.

Comment: Well, based on the information provided by the site above(very first link), the 2 .js files should take care of that

Comment: If I'm incorrect, could you please be a little bit more specific, on how to correct this issue? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, your code doesn't include the call to leanModal(). However, on your page leanModal isn't defined. I would think that one of your scripts (likely a plugin) is causing leanModal to not load properly. I was able to make it work on your page by loading the code for leanModal in the console after all other code had been run. Try including leanModal at the end of your page, and then include the following code:

```
$('#modaltrigger').leanModal();
```

Be sure to customize your options parameter for placement, closing, etc.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks so much. Is it jquery? i.e. when you suggest I put it at the bottom of the page, do I put it within <script> tags?

Comment: Yes, you want script tags like this. <script>$('#modaltrigger').leanModal();</script>. This line makes use of the jquery object.